# file_get_contents gerando erro 500

Tags: php

Tenho um arquivo [php](/questions/tagged/php) que dá um `file_get_contents` em arquivos [json](/questions/tagged/json).
O PHP consegue enxergar os arquivos porque o `file_exists` funciona certinho.
Porém, se eu der `file_get_contents` no mesmo arquivo que o `file_exists` o PHP me retorna:

> erro 500 (interno do servidor).

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); $jogosF = 1; $datadehj = date("Y-m-d"); $horaAgora = date("H:i"); $array = array(); $tempo = (10 * 60); while(file_exists("../../../txts/bkpjogosF". $jogosF .".json")) {
$conteudo = file_get_contents("../../../txts/bkpjogosF". $jogosF .".json");
$conteudo = json_decode($conteudo);

foreach ($conteudo->data as $jogosDia) {
    if($jogosDia->odds->data != null) {
        $dataInicio = $jogosDia->starting_date;
        $horaInicio = $jogosDia->starting_time;
        if ($datadehj == $dataInicio && ((strtotime($horaAgora) + $tempo) < strtotime($horaInicio))) {
            $idMatch = $jogosDia->id;
            $timeCasa = $jogosDia->homeTeam->name;
            $escudoCasa = $jogosDia->homeTeam->logo;
            $timeFora = $jogosDia->awayTeam->name;
            $escudoFora = $jogosDia->awayTeam->logo;
            foreach ($jogosDia->odds->data as $oddses) {
                foreach ($oddses->types->data as $joOdds) {
                    if ($joOdds->type == "1x2") {
                        $bookmakerId = $oddses->bookmaker_id;
                        foreach ($joOdds->odds->data as $jogum) {
                            switch ($jogum->label) {
                                case 1:
                                $cotationC = $jogum->value;
                                break;
                                case 2:
                                $cotationF = $jogum->value;
                                break;
                                case "X":
                                $cotationEmp = $jogum->value;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        break 2;
                    }
                }
            }
            $datas = new DateTime($dataInicio);
            $horas = new DateTime($horaInicio);
            $horaInicio = $horas->format('H:i');
            $dataInicio = $datas->format('d/m/Y');
            $array[] = array(
            "horaI" => $horaInicio,
            "DataI" => $dataInicio,
            "timeCasa" => $timeCasa,
            "timeFora" => $timeFora,
            "idPartida" => $idMatch,
            "cotTimeC" => $cotationC,
            "cotEmp" => $cotationEmp,
            "cotTimeF" => $cotationF,
            "escudoC" => $escudoCasa,
            "escudoF" => $escudoFora,
            "bookmaker" => $bookmakerId
            );
        }
    }
}
$jogosF++;
fclose($handle); } $sorteador = usort($array, "Meusort"); echo json_encode($array); function Meusort($a, $b) { if($a == $b) { return 0; } return ($a<$b)?-1:1; } ?>
```

Obs: A pasta no servidor tem `chmod -R 777` arquivo, ou seja, permissão total. Eu já tentei usar o `fopen`, e deu o mesmo erro.
No LOCALHOST com `XAMPP` ele funciona.

Comment: E qual erro é retornado?

Comment: Qual a versão do seu PHP no servidor? Não seria a 5.3? Consegue baixar os logs gerados pelo `error_log=` (php.ini) do php?

Comment: "GET https://site.com 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"","status":500,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"_classes/jogosBack.php","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}

Comment: Estes erros me retornam no console e a minha versão do php é a 5.0

Comment: O erro que o php retorna pra vc, não o status code do request @Krint . Caso esteja rodando em produção, tente habilitar o report de erros do php

Comment: Quer dizer do log? Estou tentando encontrar

Comment: normalmente o apache salva em /var/logs/, mas ajuda se vc colocar no começo do script o seguinte:
`ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 'On' );
    ini_set( 'track_errors', 'On' );`

Comment: pode ser que nao tenha nada a ver com o file_get_contents, se está habilitado no php.ini... ai só saberemos com o log do erro

Comment: Opa, me retornou o erro e eu descobri que era porque a memória estava em exaustão, pesquisei e botei essa linha de comando ini_set("memory_limit", "256M"). Agora funcionou. Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

**file_get_contents** é uma função que dependendo de como você usar pode representar uma falha de segurança, por isso a utilização dela é ativada pelo **php.ini**

Se você utilizar ela sem habilitar no php.ini retornará este erro 500.

Para habilitar altere:

```
allow_url_fopen = 1
```

Porém é **ALTAMENTE** recomendado que se utilize o **CURL** ao invés desta função.

```
function get_content($URL){
    $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
}
```

Uso: `echo get_content('http://example.com');`

Comment: este allow_url_fopen é no php.ini ou no arquivo do script.php? E o curl funciona quando vai utilizar para um arquivo que está no mesmo servidor que o script.php?

Comment: allow_url_fopen é no php.ini

Para um arquivo no mesmo servidor eu utilizaria o file_get_contents mesmo.

E se o arquivo for maior que 1MB eu utilizaria funções file. Tipo fread

Comment: Eu usei os dois, e continua dando o erro 500

Comment: Ah, eu encontrei o allow_url_fopen e ele estava assim: "allow_url_fopen = on"